# How to upload images using report service webservice

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We have several reports that use .png images for company logos in the header of the reports.

We are deploying reports using the SQL SSRS 2010 webservice. The idea is that the deployment must be done automatically with a script that invokes the SSRS webservice, and it must be 100% unattended

So far, we've successfully uploaded the reports, however, we are not sure how to upload the .png images

Is there any of the webservices methods that can accomplish this? Or is there a way to copy the file directly to somewhere

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single file, just upload it directly from SSRS. If you have multiple files, create a new Reporting Service project and add all the images to that project and upload all those images to a new folder `Images` in SSRS. This is really simple and I would recommend this.

Quick references:

https://www.tutorialgateway.org/upload-file-to-ssrs-report-manager/

[Bulk uploading images to SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854748/bulk-uploading-images-to-ssrs)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention in my question that the deployment must be unattended, handled by a script.
That's why we need to use the webservice.